# awk match and merge two files on basis of key values

Tags: bash, join, sed, awk

I have two files in which `$3,$4 = $3,$2`.

file1:

```
1211,A2,ittp,1,IPSG,a2,PA,3000,3000  
1311,A4,iztv,1,IPSG,a4,PA,240,250  
1411,B4,iztq,0,IPSG,b4,PA,230,250
```

file2:

```
TP,0,nttp,0.865556,0.866667  
TP,1,ittp,50.7956,50.65  
TP,1,iztv,5.42444,13.8467  
TP,0,iztq,645.194,490.609
```

I want to merge these files and print a new file like if `file1 $3,$4 = file2 $3,$2` then print merged file like

```
TP,1211,A2,ittp,1,IPSG,a2,PA,3000,3000,0.865556,0.866667  
TP,1311,A4,iztv,1,IPSG,a4,PA,240,250,50.7956,50.65  
TP,1411,B4,iztq,0,IPSG,b4,PA,230,250,5.42444,13.8467
```

BOTH THE FILES ARE CSV FILES.

I tried using `awk` but I'm not getting the desired output. It's printing only file1.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3,$4]=$3$2;next}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10 a[$1] }' OFS=, 1.csv 2.csv
```

Comment: When you're reading the first file, you need to store `$0` in `a[$3,$4]`. When you're reading the second file, you need to look up `a[$3,$2]` to get the matching line from the first file, and then combine it with the current line and print them.

Comment: Unfortunately, `join` won't work for you because it can only match the files on one field, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=",";}
         NR == FNR {a[$3,$4] = $0;}
         NR != FNR && a[$3,$2] {print $1, a[$3,$2], $4, $5;}' 1.csv 2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4,$3]=$0;next}($2,$3) in a{print $1,a[$2,$3],$4,$5}' FS=, OFS=, f1 f2
TP,1211,A2,ittp,1,IPSG,a2,PA,3000,3000,50.7956,50.65
TP,1311,A4,iztv,1,IPSG,a4,PA,240,250,5.42444,13.8467
TP,1411,B4,iztq,0,IPSG,b4,PA,230,250,645.194,490.609
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Join
If i1 and i2 are the input files

```
cat i1.txt | awk -F',' '{print $3 "-" $4 "," $1 "," $2 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9}' | sort > s1.txt
cat i2.txt | awk -F',' '{print $3 "-" $2 "," $1 "," $4 "," $5 }' | sort > s2.txt
join -t',' s1.txt s2.txt | tr '-' ',' > t12.txt
cat t12.txt | awk -F ',' '{print $10 "," $3 "," $4 "," $1 "," $2 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9 "," $11 "," $12 }'
```